# How to prevent Browser returning default value of int when input is an int parameter in the URL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

```
  public IActionResult Info(int id)
            {
                return Content(id + "");
            }
```

Whenever I input Jan/Info/2 the browser returns me the value 0. Why is this and how can I fix this? I'm using MVC core 1.1. UrlParameter.Optional is also not present in Visual Studio for some reason it's not accessible.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Naam",
                    template: "{controller=Jan}/{action}/{voornaam}");
                routes.MapRoute(
                     name: "Info",
                     template: "{controller=Jan}/{action}/{id}");

            }


 public IActionResult Naam(string voornaam)
        {

            return Content(voornaam);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you already have another route registration which is matching the exact pattern. As per that registration, it will read the value and assign to the `voornaam` parameter.

So this should work

```
public IActionResult Info(int voornaam)
{
    return Content(voornaam + "");
}
```

Since you have unique names for your action method, you do not need to specify the custom routes for each action method. The default route registration will work fine.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "defaultroutes",
        template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}",
        defaults: new { controller = "jan" });
});
```

Assuming your controller looks like this

```
public class JanController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Info(int id)
    {
        return Content(id + " : id");
    }
    public IActionResult Naam(string voornaam)
    {
        return Content(voornaam+ ": param value");
    }
}
```

When you access `yourSite/jan/info/123`, The `Info` method will handle that and when you request `yourSite/jan/Naam?voornaam=shyju` ,the Naam method will handle that.

If you want to support url structure like `yourSite/jan/Naam/shyju` instead of the explicit querystring, you can specify a route pattern on that action method with attribute routing

```
public class JanController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Info(int id)
    {
        return Content(id + " id");
    }
    [Route("[controller]/[action]/{voornaam}")]
    public IActionResult Naam(string voornaam)
    {
        return Content(voornaam + " : param value");
    }
}
```

Now when you request `yourSite/jan/Naam/shyju`, The Naam method will be called and the string "shyju" will be available in the `voornaam` parameter

Comment: I'm really not able to comprehend the route constraints. could you please construct one which I could apply to this issue ?

Comment: Do you have another action method which accepts the string param in the JanController ?